# Smart Tablet Device Vulnerabilities

Tags: smartphone, monitoring

My son and I have a cybersecurity concern. Somebody somehow compromised his tablet, accessed his files, and emailed them to him from something like guerrilla mail but we cannot figure out how.

Our Malwarebytes shows no evidence of threats. His settings revoke all camera, storage, microphone, and any other personal permissions. We searched the system file directory for anything suspicious including fake apks.

There are no suspicious processes or activities running other than Google and other similar data collecting user apps such as firefox or email. He is using App Manager from f-droid and we identified that firefox has 3 trackers, 2 splits, and a large heap. Some google apps we cleaned the cache, storage, force stopped, and disabled.

We used and uninstalled cc cleaner to clear hidden cache and speed up ram. We used lte cleaner and libre av. He uses a vpn, duckduckgo and other private search engines and browsers. For a while he tried Netguard and discovered it disabled the vpn since it uses the vpn services on android. He tried TOR but the proxy usually disables itself after a day or so of installation.

He is certain he is being monitored. He was in drug rings for a number of years. As a father, I've done what I can to help him out but do not have the technical expertise to surpass this. He is now five years clean and has no record. Some of his past acquaintances know about the files although he never discussed them with anyone but me. They seem like they may have spoken with the police. None of his files actually pose any threat. They are simply personal information. We consider the motive may be the business and general reputation of individuals and their profit but do not know if it is possible to avoid.

Would something like a device sweep show something we overlooked, and would it be worth looking in to prices for this? What other tools could we use to find vulnerabilities if we wanted to try going about it ourselves? Could we order an interpol like device offline?

Comment: Make sure the tablet has the latest updates installed. If it's not running Android 11, then it's not running the latest version of Android. The company who sold you the tablet might not be providing updates for it anymore in which case it won't be secure because it won't have the latest security patches installed. Are these files stored on the tablet, or in a cloud account like Google Drive or Dropbox?

Comment: He checks those regularly along with the security update and google play updates. The chrome and android system webview would not update through google play and so he disabled chrome. It could have been a browser from f droid that was updated late. The files used to be on a cloud. That cloud is not linked to the tablet but after reviewing other questions he thinks it may have been done directly through another website that was granted access to the cloud.

Comment: Would it make more sense for it to have been done by a Peer who may have been bribed? Or someone in the local area? Edited, in addition: He came across problems with his cloud a number of years ago so he says he is Weary about using them again.